# Auto navigate (scroll) to certain table row

Tags: html-table

I have a table with few thousand records on few pages in a simple html table.. I made a search function that works fine apart from one thing... It displays only one result in a table (which is great cause it means it works!).But... I was wondering is there a way to display back the table with all records, with the one that i was searching for in the middle and highlighted? Here's a simplified table that I have :

```php
<table class="nogap" cellpadding="1" bgcolor="#00000" cellspacing="1"  style="margin:110px 0 0 5px; width:100%; border-color:#B6D6F6;" >
  <tbody>
  <?php include 'dbconn.php';?>

   $con = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass,$db) or  (header( 'Location: errorpage.php' ));

   if (mysqli_connect_errno($con)) {  header( 'Location: errorpage.php' );  }

   $sql = "SELECT * FROM $tb1 ORDER BY (Serial_num +1) LIMIT $offset, $rowsperpage";
   $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql) or (header( 'Location: errorpage.php' ));
   $row = mysqli_num_rows($result);

   while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
   {

     $product = $row['Prod_type'].$row['Serial_num'];

     <tr id="mstrTable" class="lovelyrow">
     <td width="5%"><?php echo $product;?></td>
     <td width="5%"><?php echo $row['Customer'];?></td>
     <td width="7%">
     <a href="#"     
        onmouseover="ajax_showTooltip(window.event,'getptn.php?prd=<?php echo $p;?>',this);return false" 
        onmouseout="ajax_hideTooltip()">
          <?php echo$row['Prod_info'];?>
     </a>
     </td>
     </tr>
}
</table>
```

Thanks!

Comment: yeah thats better , thanx!

Answer (score 0):

First of all don't give the same html id attribute to each row (mstrTable). Html Ids should be unique per page.
Instead mark table rows with unique ids, eg:

```
$html .= "<td id='row_".$row['id']."'>"
```

Then do a search query first, remember item id, figure out what page should be queried, query the whole page, attach classess 'greyedout' and 'highlighted' to rows accordingly and then you might try this javascript function to scroll down to the item:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.scrollIntoView